# Why are these changes to date not taking effect?

Tags: php

I have this code that should be changing the day of the output, but I'm not getting any change.  Can anyone see what is wrong?

```
<?php 
$tempStartDate = "2011-07-04 15:00:00";
$TempDaysFromEvent = "-14";

$newtempStartDate = explode(" ", $tempStartDate);
echo "New Temp Start Date: ".$newtempStartDate[0];
echo "<br>";
list($year, $month, $day) = explode("-", $newtempStartDate[0]);
echo $year." ". $month. " ". $day;
echo "<br>";

$tempStartDate  =  $tempEndDate  =  date("Y-m-d", mktime(0,0,0,$month,($day+$tempDaysFromEvent),$year));
echo "TempStart Date:".$tempStartDate."<br>";

?>
```

This is giving me this output:

```
New Temp Start Date: 2011-07-04
2011 07 04
TempStart Date:2011-07-04
```

But I would expect it to give me:

```
New Temp Start Date: 2011-07-04
2011 07 04
TempStart Date:2011-06-20
```

Comment: Ah I just caught it-stupid typo actually-I just caught it:
$TempDaysFromEvent = "-14";
should be
$tempDaysFromEvent = "-14";

Comment: Maybe a typo in your question or maybe it's the problem.  PHP is case-sensitive and you have defined $TempDaysFromEvent and then when you try to use it it's $tempDaysFromEvent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a capital when you define `$TempDaysFromEvent` so change it to this

```
$tempStartDate  =  $tempEndDate  =  date("Y-m-d", mktime(0,0,0,$month,($day+$TempDaysFromEvent),$year));
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be getting this notice:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: tempDaysFromEvent in C:\tmp\test.php on line 12
```

Your variable is actually `$TempDaysFromEvent`. Variables in PHP are case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo there

`$tempDaysFromEvent` instead of `$TempDaysFromEvent`

Answer (score 1):

A much less complicated solution:

```
$tempStartDate = "2011-07-04 15:00:00";
print date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-14 days', strtotime($tempStartDate)));
```

Comment: actually-I just caught it:
$TempDaysFromEvent = "-14";
should be
$tempDaysFromEvent = "-14";

Comment: I agree, but this is just a small part of the bigger code-I need those variables in other places.

Comment: @Joel you can use this method to break down the date into components as well. for instance $month = date('m', strtotime('-14 days', strtotime($start_date)))